# Why we have to wrap throw with brackets in es6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to ask if someones knows the reason why

`const fun = msg => throw new Error( msg );` is invalid JS while

`const fun = msg => { throw new Error( msg ); }` is valid

Since

`const fun = msg => new Error( t );` is valid

Someone (I would) would expect also the case with `throw` to be valid JS.

**Is there any reason behind this choice? e.g. does it makes it difficult to the interpreter or something?**

Comment: Because it would be equivalent to `function(msg) { return throw new Error(msg); }`

Comment: Ya, you cannot `return` a `throw`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Arrow functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) are defined like this:

```
ArrowFunction[In, Yield] :
    ArrowParameters[?Yield] [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody[?In]

ConciseBody[In] :
    [lookahead ≠ { ] AssignmentExpression[?In]
    { FunctionBody }
```

And [throw](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-throw-statement) is an statement:

```
ThrowStatement[Yield] :
    throw [no LineTerminator here] Expression[In, ?Yield] ;
```

Then the first *ConciseBody* body syntax won't work because [*AssignmentExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-rules) doesn't include statements:

```
AssignmentExpression :
    YieldExpression
    ArrowFunction
    LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
    BitwiseANDExpression : BitwiseANDExpression & EqualityExpression
    BitwiseXORExpression : BitwiseXORExpression ^ BitwiseANDExpression
    BitwiseORExpression : BitwiseORExpression | BitwiseXORExpression
```

If you use braces, then the inner part of *ConciseBody* will be a [*FunctionBody*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions), which is a list of statements. So a *ThrowStatement* is allowed.